# Server.htmlencode and TextBox with MaxSize

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, encoding

I have a TextArea input on a page. This textbox is multiline and has a maxsize of 500 characters. I am using .NET 4.0.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtOther" Width="530px" TextMode="MultiLine" Style="word-wrap: break-word;height: 300px; overflow: auto; vertical-align: top" runat="server" AutoComplete="off" MaxLength="500" />
```

The situation is this (for example): the user can enter like 499 characters in the textarea and that  that includes a "<" sign. Obviously, the < when encoded will have the &lt. That puts the length of the text entered greater than 500.

Now, the bad thing is on the code-behind it will take the text entered and do a Server.HtmlEncode of it.

If I manually type in the obviously the maxlength will be handled but it could still happen with that. If you do a cut/copy and paste then the maxlength will not be handled but I will only take the 500 characters anyway but the same situation could still happen there.

It will eventually go into a DB and the DB column is an nvarchar 500. It's not a Text or anything like that. It's an nvarchar 500 for whatever reason and it's not something I can change.

How can I have the code on the client-side encode the text entered to validate that it's still less than 500 after the encoding? I am willing to just truncate whatever is over 500 characters.

Answer (score 0):

When you have MaxLenght="500", validation occurs on the server - after the client has submitted the user input. Server.HtmlEncode is also executed on the server.

If you create a client-side, custom validator you could handle limit input to less than 500 characters and eliminate the encode issue with the 500th character being a '<' or '>'.

It would also save on round trips to your server as well.

On your web page you'll need to add a Custom Validator:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustValid500" runat="server"
     ControlToValidate ="TxtOther"
     ErrorMessage ="500 or more characters are not allowed"
     ClientValidationFunction = "ValidateLength" >
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

And a bit of javascript:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
     function validateLength(oSrc, args)
     { args.IsValid = (args.Value.length < 500); }
</script>
```

Comment: I already have a javascript to handle/work with the length. I completely spaced out the maxlength issue because of that but it's still there none-the-less. So, that I want to do is allow the user to enter or do a copy/paste. The problem is if they enter something like 499 characters; if they SAVE the server-side is going to do the Server.htmlencoding. It the result is over 500 characters it's only going to take 500 (truncate the rest) but what I want to do not allow the entire copy/paste if it's encoding it will result in > 500. How can I do that?

Comment: What I have is close to what you have albeit, without the length validator. I have a javascript instead of the CustomerValidator (which is essentially server-side rather that client-side anyway) and what I have is client-side. But it's the encoding piece on the client-side to match what the server-side will do. Is there anything I can do with that or am I just going to have to stay with the server-side?